# Automatic Upload of an image SonataMediaBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I use SonataMediaBundle to upload my images, and now I want to upload an image and the upload were more beautiful, that is to say that when you upload the image using the button, it will appear beside with a delete button for example that resets the upload, before validation and submission of the form,

Do you have any idea how to do this?

thank you very much

Comment: sure this is not built in, look at this to get an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Comment: This should do the job for you [**`MEDIABUNDLE ~ MEDIATYPE IMPROVED`**](http://sonata-project.org/blog/2013/10/11/mediabundle-mediatype-improved)